# Нахождение близости двух текстов

Tags: python

Задача, которую необходимо решить - проанализировав массив предложений необходимо предположить, к какому разделу (теме) относится этот текст для того, чтобы в конечном счёте предположить о "близости" двух таких массивов предложений. Пример: В одном тексте рассказывается об футбольном матче одной команды, а в другом - о хоккейном матче. Следовательно, эти 2 текста относятся к одному разделу "спорт" и будет "ближе" друг к другу, чем текст о компьютерных играх.

Нашёл сайт, на котором существуют различные вектора слова (https://nlpub.ru/Russian_Distributional_Thesaurus). Пример одного из таких: [словесность][литература][0.693631] - слово "словесность" является синонимом слова "литература" на 0.693631. Может ли это как-нибудь помочь в решении моей задачи? Нужна лишь подсказка, в какую сторону копать и о чём гуглить информацию. Нужно ли будет создавать нейронку и обучать её?

Answer (score 0):

Копайте в сторону "кластеризации тестов". Это целое направление в NLP, и методов там испробовано куча: самоорганизующаяся сеть Кохонена, методы К-средних, спектральной кластеризации; агломеративной кластеризации. Используется весьма широко -  когда-то то-ли Reuters то-ли  Bloomberg хвастался, что сократил 80% сотрудников занимающихся систематизацией поступающей информации внедрив систему автоматической кластеризации. Кстати в ChatGPT внутри себя некоторые элементы этих методов использует.

Comment: Стоит ли применять обучение без учителя при обучении нейронной сети? И может ли как-нибудь rdt помочь в решении этой задачи?

Comment: Что значит "стоит-ли"? Если у вас есть набранный обучающий набор данных -  на несколько (десятков) тысяч примеров, да и классификатор сформулирован заранее - то конечно, обучать лучше с учителей. Если чего бы то ни было не хватает -  то тогда применяют обучение без учителя.  Если ваше rdt - это Russian Distributional Thesaurus , то применяйте, почему нет. Главная проблема, как получать из него информацию, нужную именно вашим (т.е. выбранным вами) алгоритмам.

Comment: Да, дело в том, что обучающей модели нет. Есть лишь rdt и куча текста. Вот и хотел узнать, как это счастье связать

Comment: Ну так я написал как.  Вы спросили " Нужна лишь подсказка, в какую сторону копать и о чём гуглить информацию." -  я ответил. Вы спросили "обучающей модели нет" -  я ответил "кластеризация". Вы спросили "Нужно ли будет создавать нейронку и обучать её?" -  некоторые из пересиленных мною методов работают без нейронок. Но можно и нейронки подключить -  тут уж зависит исключительно от вашего желания.  На вопрос "как это счастье связать" -  так тут на форуме не ответить. Это вообще говоря уже "задание", а не "вопрос".